# how to have texts under tabs using XAML?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, mobile, tabview

```
            <StackLayout>
                <Frame CornerRadius="10">
                    <Grid>
                        <xyt:TabView x:Name="tabView" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <xyt:TabViewItem Text="Tab1" TextColorSelected="Orange">
                                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                                    <Label Text="I don't know. help me pls." />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </xyt:TabViewItem>
                            <xyt:TabViewItem Text="Tab2" TextColorSelected="orange">
                                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                                    <Button Text="Comment" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </xyt:TabViewItem>
                        </xyt:TabView>
                    </Grid>
                </Frame>
            </StackLayout>
```

There are two tabs in the code, Text="Tab1" and Text="Tab2," and I coded so if I click one of them, the color of the text changes to orange. The part I am stuck is that in Tab1, I want another text showing below Tab1 and I wrote  but the text doesn't show up under Tab1 nor the button I put under Tab2, , shows up. How can I make it so the texts appear under selected tabs? (I'm a beginner in this language)

I saw this one youtube video and this guy used <ContentPage.Resources>, <ResourceDictionary,  and added some stuff and later put ControlTemplate="{StaticResource CustomTab} in the code. Should I do that as well?

Comment: What is `xyt:TabView`?

Comment: @Jason I downloaded Xamarin Community Tool Kit and put xmlns:xyt="clr-namespace:Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views;assembly=Xamarin.CommunityToolkit"

Comment: try setting some explicit `HeightRequest` values on the content of each `TabViewItem`

Comment: @Jason I don't want to set a fixed height on the tabs. For example, if I set HeightRequest =180 I can see the texts inside the tabs but if I write more texts inside the tab, the height of the tab doesn't change and I can't see the full text. I want it so the tab height changes depending on the length of the text in the tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to code below on how to add text or other content showing below `Tabs`.

**SAMPLE CODE:**

```
<Frame CornerRadius="10">
    <Grid>
           <xyt:TabView
                TabStripHeight="60"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

            <xyt:TabViewItem           
                    Text="Tab 1"                 
                    TextColorSelected="Orange"
                    FontSize="12">

                <StackLayout                 
                       VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">

                    <Label 
                            Text="I don't know. help me pls" />

                </StackLayout>

            </xyt:TabViewItem>

            <xyt:TabViewItem

                    Text="Tab 2"
                    TextColorSelected="Orange"
                    FontSize="12">

                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">

                    <Button   Text="Comment" />

                </StackLayout>

            </xyt:TabViewItem>

        </xyt:TabView>

    </Grid>
 </Frame>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I just updated the answer, you may need to remove the outside  `StackLayout`. This should show up text under Tab1.

Comment: Thank you for the code! I'm sorry I didn't put it in the question but I need the tabs to be located at the bottom of the mobile screen. So I used VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" so the tabs would locate at the bottom of the screen but the tab1 and tab2 showed up but the texts inside the tab1 didn't show up. I'm avoiding using HeightRequest for the tabs since it will asign a fixed height and when I put longer text, the text won't show fully. I want so the tab is located at the bottom of the screen and when there are longer texts, the height of the tab increases - going up. Is this possible?

Comment: Thanks for the update, `TabStripPlacement` is used to set the tab at bottom or top https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/tabview#properties, you may set `TabStripPlacement= Bottom` if you need the tabs to be located at the bottom of the mobile screen.